# Website suddenly not available on chromium

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, chromium

I use a trading platform called cTrader, from IC Markets. They have a web platform that ran fine (a bit slow) on chromium, and all of the sudden, it's not working anymore. The site says my browser is not supported.

Any ideas on how could I fix this? I am using a raspberry Pi 3 B+, so full chrome is not an option, and already tried Firefox ESR.

Comment: Maybe the site has changed something? Does Firefox is working?

Comment: No, it's not working either... What could have changed?

Comment: at a guess, the site changed

Comment: @FrederickvanLingen have you used `sudo apt-get update && sudp apt-get dist-upgrade` to ensure that you have the latest version of Chromium?

Comment: @NathanielJS, thanks for your answer. I just tried and nothing... I don't know if it could be a plugin or something, but in that case, the update should have helped, right? what else could it be?

Comment: I also tried to download Exagear desktop, but they're apparently not taking any orders for the moment...

Comment: @FrederickvanLingen Exagear Desktop is discontinued since February.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, Chromium in Raspbian Buster is version 74. Not far behind the latest Chrome 77. But some websites do not recognize the browser because Chromium announces itself as 'chromium' instead of 'chrome'. So those sites assume it's some incapable browser and prevents the user from using it. Very annoying.

Fortunately there is an easy fix. I installed [User Agent Switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg) on chromium, and then created a custom User Agent string, `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36` and set it to be applied as default for all sites.  That way websites will think you are running Chrome, not Chromium.