# cTrader crash my browser (Chromium and Firefox)

Tags: raspbian, debian, chromium

I tried to run cTrader on Chromium on my RPI but during this night my browser crashed and I don't know why, same problem on my VPS in Debian 10.

An other guy have the same problem here:
[Website suddenly not available on chromium](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96378/website-suddenly-not-available-on-chromium)

Do you have a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: did you check all the logs in `/var/log` for any indications?

Comment: I found nothing in /var/log but I get this document: https://help.ctrader.com/ctrader-web/start/general
Apparently linux browser are not supported...

Comment: Do you have the latest Raspbian Buster?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Yes, the last version here https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

Comment: If the browser isn't supported, it isn't supported. If the cTrader server is checking [the user-agent string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent#User_agent_identification) for the OS, that can be spoofed with a plugin like this (chrome): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg I would be wary of spoofing the actual browser type though.